# Spring security match Principal info with request param

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, security, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

So I'm trying to validate my endpoint without IFs and such things, only with PreFilter and I basically have the following

```
@GetMapping(value = "/books/{userId}")
@PreFilter("hasRole('ADMIN') or principal.userId == pathVar.userId")
public List<Books> getBooks(@PathVariable("userId" String userId) {
   //do sth
}
```

My problem is getting the PreFilter to work, or actually to match the userId from the authenticated principal with the path variable so that each user can request only his own books.

Yes I know that I can remove the path variable and just do principal.getUserId() inside the method, but that means that I will need to have an if user is admin.

Comment: Why not create another path like '/my-books` and inject user principal?

Answer (score 0):

Okay after quite a few tries I have finally found out how to do it. In case anyone is interested:
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') or #userId == principal.userId")

This way if you are the admin you can get the books of any user, and if you are a user you can get only your own.